# glDrawArrays() segfaults when drawing too many elements

Tags: android, opengl, opengl-es, android-ndk

I have some simple OpenGL ES code in C++ that I've run on a phone running Android, a phone running webOS, and my Mac using SDL/OpenGL. The code in question just draws a `GL_LINE_STRIP` that's stored in an array of `GLfloat`s. Here's how I'm trying to do this (**version 1**):

```
GLfloat array* = new GLfloat[2048];
//later... (array gets filled)
int howMany = 1024;
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, array); checkError();
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, howMany); checkError();
```

Seems like it should be pretty straightforward. However, the above code segfaults inside OpenGL drivers on both Android and my Mac (seems to run fine on webOS, for whatever reason.) Here's what I have to do to avoid this (**version 2**):

```
GLfloat array* = new GLfloat[2048];
//later... (array gets filled)
int howMany = 1024;
for (unsigned i = 0; i < howMany; i += 789) {
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, array+i*2); checkError();
    //this is not a bug: we draw one more than we increment by, or there is a hole in the graph
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, std::min(790U, howMany-i)); checkError();
}
```

Limiting the number of lines drawn at a time consistently avoids the segfault. The number 790 was determined experimentally; at 791 it crashes on OSX (Android can go higher, though it used to be limited to 113 many versions ago... so the number seems to be consistent for each app version but not between different versions or platforms.)

There is a lot of other GL stuff going on in my app, but it's a large application and posting all of that code wouldn't be practical. So, what could possibly cause this? What possibilities should I look into?

Here's the valgrind output of my program running and crashing on OSX when I try to use version 1:

```
==85414== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==85414==    at 0x1D022993: glVertexPointer_Exec (in /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Resources/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine)
==85414==    by 0x6AA59A9: glVertexPointer (in /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib)
==85414==    by 0x2B001: draw_elements (in ./rta.app/Contents/MacOS/rta)
==85414==    by 0x2B44C: glDrawArrays (in ./rta.app/Contents/MacOS/rta)
==85414==    by 0xB639: GLImage::glDraw(int, int) (in ./rta.app/Contents/MacOS/rta)
==85414==    by 0xC292: GLLabel::glDraw(int, int) (in ./rta.app/Contents/MacOS/rta)
==85414==    by 0x1AC67: RTAPlot::drawAxes(int) (in ./rta.app/Contents/MacOS/rta)
==85414==    by 0x1B30A: RTAPlot::updateGL() (in ./rta.app/Contents/MacOS/rta)
==85414==    by 0x225F5: RTAPlotView::updateForeground() (in ./rta.app/Contents/MacOS/rta)
==85414==    by 0x19FC4: RTAComponent::update() (in ./rta.app/Contents/MacOS/rta)
==85414==    by 0x805D: AudiaApplication_private::updateGL() (in ./rta.app/Contents/MacOS/rta)
==85414==    by 0x267DF: AudiaApplication::run() (in ./rta.app/Contents/MacOS/rta)
==85414==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==85414==    at 0x1D02268F: glVertexPointer_Exec (in /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Resources/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine)
==85414== 
==85414== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==85414==    at 0x1D022E0C: glTexCoordPointer_Exec (in /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Resources/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine)
==85414==    by 0x6AA5216: glTexCoordPointer (in /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib)
==85414==    by 0x2B279: draw_elements (in ./rta.app/Contents/MacOS/rta)
==85414==    by 0x2B44C: glDrawArrays (in ./rta.app/Contents/MacOS/rta)
==85414==    by 0xB639: GLImage::glDraw(int, int) (in ./rta.app/Contents/MacOS/rta)
==85414==    by 0xC292: GLLabel::glDraw(int, int) (in ./rta.app/Contents/MacOS/rta)
==85414==    by 0x1AC67: RTAPlot::drawAxes(int) (in ./rta.app/Contents/MacOS/rta)
==85414==    by 0x1B30A: RTAPlot::updateGL() (in ./rta.app/Contents/MacOS/rta)
==85414==    by 0x225F5: RTAPlotView::updateForeground() (in ./rta.app/Contents/MacOS/rta)
==85414==    by 0x19FC4: RTAComponent::update() (in ./rta.app/Contents/MacOS/rta)
==85414==    by 0x805D: AudiaApplication_private::updateGL() (in ./rta.app/Contents/MacOS/rta)
==85414==    by 0x267DF: AudiaApplication::run() (in ./rta.app/Contents/MacOS/rta)
==85414==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==85414==    at 0x1D022A6B: glTexCoordPointer_Exec (in /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Resources/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine)
==85414== 
==85414== Invalid read of size 8
==85414==    at 0x1D0B9166: gleRunVertexSubmitImmediate (in /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Resources/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine)
==85414==    by 0x1D0B84FB: gleLLVMArrayFunc (in /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Resources/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine)
==85414==    by 0x1D0A14F2: gleDrawArraysOrElements_ExecCore (in /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Resources/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine)
==85414==    by 0x1D0A2A04: glDrawElements_IMM_Exec (in /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Resources/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine)
==85414==    by 0x6AA304F: glDrawElements (in /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib)
==85414==    by 0x2B2DB: draw_elements (in ./rta.app/Contents/MacOS/rta)
==85414==    by 0x2B44C: glDrawArrays (in ./rta.app/Contents/MacOS/rta)
==85414==    by 0x1FEF6: RTAPlotCanvas::drawLineStrip(float*, unsigned int) (in ./rta.app/Contents/MacOS/rta)
==85414==    by 0x1E91A: RTAPlotCanvas::updateGL() (in ./rta.app/Contents/MacOS/rta)
==85414==    by 0x1B318: RTAPlot::updateGL() (in ./rta.app/Contents/MacOS/rta)
==85414==    by 0x225F5: RTAPlotView::updateForeground() (in ./rta.app/Contents/MacOS/rta)
==85414==    by 0x19FC4: RTAComponent::update() (in ./rta.app/Contents/MacOS/rta)
==85414==  Address 0xc0000000 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==85414== 
==85414== 
==85414== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==85414==  General Protection Fault
==85414==    at 0x10AED0: misaligned_stack_error_ (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==85414==    by 0x1E45E87: -[NSCustomReleaseData dealloc] (in /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit)
==85414==    by 0x1E45E37: -[NSBitmapImageRep _freeData] (in /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit)
==85414==    by 0x1E45DCA: -[NSBitmapImageRep _freeImage] (in /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit)
==85414==    by 0x1E45D74: -[NSBitmapImageRep dealloc] (in /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit)
==85414==    by 0x171DF37: CFRelease (in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation)
==85414==    by 0x1748691: __CFArrayReleaseValues (in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation)
==85414==    by 0x171E100: _CFRelease (in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation)
==85414==    by 0x1D89F7A: -[NSImage dealloc] (in /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit)
==85414==    by 0x20857D4: -[NSCursor dealloc] (in /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit)
==85414==    by 0xDFE33: QZ_FreeWMCursor (in /opt/PalmPDK/host/lib/libSDL-1.2.0.11.2.dylib)
==85414==    by 0xCA11F: SDL_FreeCursor (in /opt/PalmPDK/host/lib/libSDL-1.2.0.11.2.dylib)
--85414:0:schedule VG_(sema_down): read returned -4
```

Note that the first two conditional jump errors happen every time, and might not be a problem with my app. The invalid read error only occurs when I try to use version 1 on OSX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may not be related to your vertex array at all. For example there might be still pointers to the other vertex attribues set, and of course if those are of smaller buffers than the new vertex array you'll get a segfault.

If you look closely at your valgrind output you'll see, that there's still a texture coord pointer set.

So what I suggest is you disable all vertex attribute arrays you don't need:

```
glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
/* ... */
```

in your case

```
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```

Comment: Of course, it seems obvious now. That did it! `GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY` was indeed the culprit. I can't believe this one stumped me for so long :) thanks.

Comment: If you start "measuring" numbers that "make your program work" this is always a clue, that something is going wrong in a fundamental way. Of course if your program interacts with the physical world it's all about measurement. But if your memory access patterns depend on some magic numbers it is time to stop messing in the code and start with thinking what's actually going on. In your case you stumbled over something that would even break in languages that don't have pointers. For example the Python OpenGL bindings are susceptible for this kind of bug too, and would crash in the same way.